# Kompose propagates underscores in names from env files

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kompose

i've been trying to deploy intelowl [1] into helm chart, but kompose [2] still retains the underscores in the names. Is there a way to avoid that / have i made a mistake in translating it, or is this a bug?

Command used to transform it was `./kompose convert -c -f ./intelowl/docker/default.yml -o intelowlchart`

[1] https://github.com/intelowlproject/IntelOwl/tree/master/docker
[2] https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/releases/download/v1.22.0/kompose-linux-amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to require manual renaming. No other solution found.